# Citing a Working Paper

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am citing some working paper in my work. However, in the reference list full details of these papers are not shown. For example consider this paper.

```
         @unpublished{Schwarcz2008,
         address = {Durham},
         author = {Schwarcz, Steven L.},
         file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ahmed Arif/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Schwarcz - 2008 - Systemic Risk.pdf:pdf},
         institution = {Duke Law School},
         pages = {193--249},
         series = {Research Paper Series},
         title = {{Systemic Risk}},
         url = {http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract{\_}id=1008326},
         year = {2008}
         }
```

In the reference list only this information is appeared.

> Schwarcz, S. L. (2008). Systemic Risk.

However, if same paper is cited in word using Mendley. Following details are shown.

> Schwarcz, S. L. (2008). Systemic Risk (Research Paper Series No. 163). Durham. Retrieved from http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1008326

Is it possible to show the full details for working paper in references in LaTex. A minimal working example is given here.

```
      \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
      \usepackage{authblk}
      \usepackage{titlesec}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[english]{babel}
      \usepackage{natbib}
      \setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
      \title{Systemic Risk}
      \author{Ahmed Arif}
      \begin{document}
        \maketitle
      \section{Systemic Risk}
      \citet{Schwarcz2008} has provided a definition of systemic risk.

      \bibliographystyle{APA}
      \bibliography{library}

      \end{document}
```

Comment: This depends on what bst file you are using or how you have biblatex configured. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @Andrew I have given the working example now. Please see my question again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the style of your bibTeX items is determined by the `\bibliographystyle{...}` command. For example `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` gives more descriptive bibTex items. See https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles for a few examples.

As Andrew points out, it depends on what .bst file you are using. The is what you specify with `\bibliographystyle{...}`. For example, `\bibliographystyle{mybst}` would look for "mybst.bst" in your LaTeX search path and in the folder of your main .tex file. You can define your own style by creating a custom .bst file. (althought, that is a bit involved) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546396/bib-style-format-for-bibtext-bst-file-explained-by-an-example#3560012) and [this reference](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) if you are curious about that.